# using DotNetOpenAuth to verify a JavaScript OAuthSimple querystring

Tags: oauth, dotnetopenauth

I'm working on a project that will generate an OAuth querystring in JavaScript, using HTTPS and in internal application, so security is not a major concern at this point (figured I'd mention that up front )

The JavaScript querystring is used to call a C# script on a different server and domain, essentially to pass data from the internal application to the C# application, and allow to verification that a) the query comes from the right source, and b) the query is valid and hasn't expired, etc.

OAuthSimple gives me a signed URL like this:
http://www.myremotesite.com/mycodepath/mycodefile.aspx?firstname=Kevin&lastname=Blount&oauth_consumer_key=ThisIsTheConsumerKey&oauth_nonce=nuOoM&oauth_signature=DAoaSxD5SvVFTTDNSxiTbANzGlc%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1313162452

My question is, one the C# side of things.. what do I do next? I've two thoughts, but I can't work out which I need to explore:

1. using C# generate a new signed URL and compare the two (or just compare the oauth_signature values)
2. take the querystring and somehow decrypt/decode it and verify it.

I'm told that DotNetOpenAuth is the standard to use, but I can't figure out my next step using it.

Can I get some advice on what I need to look into, or articles that explain how I should proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the instructions on DotNetOpenAuth and make sure you understand it. I haven't used it previously, but have heard good things about it.

The oAuth server will do several steps:

1. Validate version - Is the client using the correct version of oAuth for you to handle
2. Validate TimeStamp - All timestamps must be in UTC to avoid Time Zone problems
3. Validate Nonce - Has it been used previously allowed time range
4. Validate Signature - Get the private key from the consumer key, compute the signature using the values passed in the parameters and compare to the actual signature.
5. Once the message has passed all the checks, then the server will return the resource requested by the message

Comment: Hi Mark - thanks for the response. I have read the DNOA site, and don't understand it, which is why I'm posting my question ;) I didn't find any instructions on the site, perhaps you could direct me to them? I've tried searching the site for 'oauth' and other keywords, but don't find anything that explains what I need to do to verify that my OAuthSimple (JavaScript) URL is valid. Your steps make sense, but only if I can understand how DNOA helps me do this. Using the OAuthBase.cs from OAuth.net kinda works, but i'm not able to get exact verification.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Service Provider Sample Code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/files/releases/v3.4/v3.4.7/) for DotNetOpenAuth. Look under Samples/OAuthServiceProvider. That is an implementation of an OAuth Server that should help you get going.

I apologize for not being more help, but I've haven't used that code before.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, Mark. I decided against using DotNetOpenAuth, and stuck with the OAuthBase.cs class from oauth.net, where the JavaScript OAuth Library also comes from. I figured using JavaScript and C# code from the same source makes more sense (in my case) than trying to figure out DNOA. I'm marking your initial reply as the answer though, as the steps for validation are very useful regardless of which C# OAuth library I use. Cheers!